# JPA find closest shop feature

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is the thing: when a client makes an order on a website, he passes his zip code. On my program I'm receiving that zip code, get coordinates of it and return the list of closest shop (ordered by distance) from db. Also I have to store in the db the closest shop for him (just internal info)

For now I have smth like this

```
@Repository
public interface ClosestRepository extends JpaRepository<Closest,Long> {

@Query("SELECT new Closest(s, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(ad.coordinates.latitude)) * cos(radians(ad.coordinates.longitude) - radians(:longitude)) + sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(ad.coordinates.latitude)))) as d) FROM Shop s JOIN s.address ad ORDER BY d")
List<Closest> findClosestOrderedByCoordinates(@Param("latitude") final double latitude, @Param("longitude") final double longitude);
}
```

The closest entity is this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "closest")
public class Closest implements Comparable<Closest> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
private Shop shop;

@Column(name = "zone")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Zone zone;

@Column(name = "distance")
private Double distance;

public Closest() {
}

public Closest(Shop shop, Double distance) {
    this.shop = shop;
    this.distance = distance;
    zone = Zone.getByDistance(distance);
}
}
```

But this works only if I @JsonIgnore the shop in Closest entity. Internally it is set and saved properly, but I can't get the List with nested Shop info in it.
Is it possible/correct to create entity list based on another entities (like I did in repo)?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW `cos`, `sin`, `acos`, `radians` etc are all not valid JPQL functions, so portability has just been thrown away. Use of a geospatial type and geospatial function would give the answer with far simpler query.

Comment: @DN1 ok thanks, but as you can see there is not only ordering by distance task. As well as that, I need both to store the closest shop WITH distance to client in km AND specific Zone attribute (internal business logic). My question is how can I create an entity from another entity with some nested relations?